# Ошибка записи в файл lock

Tags: php, windows

Выдаёт ошибку при попытке записать информацию в файл формата `.lock`:

```
file_put_contents(): Only 0 of 10 bytes written, possibly out of free disk space
```

Данная ошибка вылетает только на windows. На линуксе всё нормально.
Кусок кода для записи в файл:

```
file_put_contents($this->lockDirectory . $action . '.lock', $time);
```

Comment: Ну, а место-то есть на диске? Оно ж пишет, что место кончилось.

Comment: Если бы всё было так легко, то не писал бы вопрос